# Replicate Windows 7 "add a device" dialog in C#

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7, dialog

I'm looking to replicate the "Add a device" dialog (I can't attach a picture because of my reputation, but just go in "Devices and Printers" and click on 
Add a device") from Windows 7 in C#, more specifically the kind of "ListView" control. Is there any control in the .NET Framework that would allow me to do a listing of items with an Icon on the left and the text on the right?

Worst case scenario, I'll just override the paint method of a ListView.

Comment: Are you using WinForms, or WPF?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, standard Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found the answer. It was a lot more easy than I thought. I didn't realize how the "Tile" mode draw items. So, I just did a small DrawItem method.

This works for me, but would need modification for any other projects.

```
    private void Devices_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        e.DrawBackground();

        // Get the device image, changes depending of it's status.
        Image DeviceIcon = Devices.LargeImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex];

        // Draw the device image.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(DeviceIcon, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);

        // Draw the device name.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, new Font(Devices.Font, Devices.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds.Left + DeviceIcon.Width + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 3);

        // Draw the device type.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.SubItems[1].Text, Devices.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds.Left + DeviceIcon.Width + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 18);

        // Draw the device port.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.SubItems[2].Text, Devices.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds.Left + DeviceIcon.Width + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 33);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    }
```